# Method to check what stylesheet has been applied

Tags: javascript, html, css

**The problem:** I want to see which stylesheet has precedence in the document.

**The proposition:** Add a class that has the same name in all stylesheets with unique values. Apply this class to one DIV at the end of the document and see which value was applied.

**The code:**

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 479px)" href="css/mediaScreen/max479.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-width: 767px)" href="css/mediaScreen/min480Max767.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 991px)" href="css/mediaScreen/min768Max991.css" />

<body onload="checksheet();">
<!--content here-->
  <div class="sheetValue" id="sheetValue">
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

Each stylesheet has a unique value which are all displayed below:

```
.sheetValue {color:#FF0; visibility:hidden; display:none;}/* Yellow stylesheet */
.sheetValue {color:#0F0; visibility:hidden; display:none;}/* Green stylesheet */
.sheetValue {color:#F00; visibility:hidden; display:none;}/* Red stylesheet */
.sheetValue {color:#00C; visibility:hidden; display:none;}/* Blue stylesheet */
```

JS:

Here the color value is checked and the result determines which stylesheet took precedence. The result is added to a custom value in the 'document' object so it can be referenced after execution of the function. This is a new idea to me so would appreciate feedback, my reasoning is that the document object will not be deleted so can always be referenced. This way the function only needs to execute once and its value can be looked up continuously without touching the DOM. This provides a lookup time below 0 ms, preliminary execution for the onload is in the region of sub 0 to 1 or 2 ms (I have only used the date functionality to measure this for now).

```
function checksheet(){
    var ac1 = document.getElementById('sheetValue');
    if (window.getComputedStyle(ac1,null).getPropertyValue("color") === "rgb(255, 255, 0)"){
        document.sheetType = "Yellow";
    }
    else if (window.getComputedStyle(ac1,null).getPropertyValue("color") === "rgb(0, 255, 0)"){
        document.sheetType = "Green";
    }
else if (window.getComputedStyle(ac1,null).getPropertyValue("color") === "rgb(255, 0, 0)"){
        document.sheetType = "Red";
    }
    else if (window.getComputedStyle(ac1,null).getPropertyValue("color") === "rgb(0, 0, 204)"){
        document.sheetType = "Blue";
    }
}
```

Any comments, feedback or outright dismissals welcome.

Comment: Nice, all these headings in this question. But I miss one: 'The question'. What exactly is the problem you're having? In what way doesn't your current code work?

Comment: The problem/question is I need to use custom solutions depending on what stylesheet has been applied. An addition: if adding to the document object is not considered bad practice I would create a 'custom' value and add any custom values in there, that way any calls to the document object will not be slowed down when the object is being searched (please correct me if this is wrong, this way it prevents cluttering of the document object).

Comment: @GolezTrol Oh, and it is also mostly for opinion to see if anyone considers any of this the wrong approach. Constructive criticism :)

Answer (score 0):

The part which confuses me is your use-case for doing so. From the code sample you provide, it appears that you're including a particular css file based on querying for media properties.

While I won't go into much detail about media queries here, what you're trying to achieve can easily be computed by measuring the screen dimensions using javascript (screen.width, document.documentElement.clientWidth) which will be a far better solution than checking for a computed css value (ex: what if the computed color is returned in hex?).

Look at 
http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/08/combining_media.html

While it doesn't work in older browsers, there's also window.matchMedia which can be used like this:

```
window.matchMedia('only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1991px)')
```